# Translation Verification Mathematical Logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

May you please tell me if my translation to mathematical logic is correct?

Also if I need more than one variable, may you explain me why? I am lost about when I need one variable and when I need more than one.

***Any car with good brakes is safe to drive and safe to ride in. So if a car is new and if all new cars have good brakes, then it is safe to ride in.***

***Premise:***

(For all x) [(Cx and Gx) implies (Dx and Rx)]

***Conclusion:***

(There exists y) (For all x) ([(Cy and Ny) and ((Cx and Nx) implies Gx)] implies (Ry))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, your conclusion isn't quite right. First note that when it says 'if a car ...'  it may *look* like this is about *some* car, but they really say this about *any* car.  It is like: 'A lion is a dangerous animal' ... if you think about it, they really mean that as a universal, not just about some lion.

So, you get:

$\forall x ((Cx \land Nx) \rightarrow (\forall y ((Cy \land Ny) \rightarrow Gy) \rightarrow Rx))$

If you want to take the quantifier to the front, you can just the following general Prenex Laws, so called because they do exactly that: take the quantifiers to the front, and any FOL statement with all quantifiers at the front is said to be in Prenex Normal Form:

$Q \land \exists x P(x) \Leftrightarrow \exists x (Q \land P(x))$

$Q \land \forall x P(x) \Leftrightarrow \forall x (Q \land P(x))$

$Q \lor \exists x P(x) \Leftrightarrow \exists x (Q \lor P(x))$

$Q \lor \forall x P(x) \Leftrightarrow \forall x (Q \lor P(x))$

$Q \rightarrow \exists x P(x) \Leftrightarrow \exists x (Q \rightarrow P(x))$

$Q \rightarrow \forall x P(x) \Leftrightarrow \forall x (Q \rightarrow P(x))$

$\exists x P(x) \rightarrow Q \Leftrightarrow \forall x (P(x) \rightarrow Q)$

$\forall x P(x)\rightarrow Q \Leftrightarrow \exists x (P(x) \rightarrow Q)$

Note that for the last two, the quantifier changes!  This is because:

$\exists x P(x) \rightarrow Q \Leftrightarrow $ (rewrite conditional)

$\neg \exists x P(x) \lor Q \Leftrightarrow $ (quantifier negation)

$\forall x \neg P(x) \lor Q \Leftrightarrow $ (Prenex Law for $\lor$)

$\forall x (\neg P(x) \lor Q) \Leftrightarrow $ (rewrite conditional)

$\forall x (P(x) \rightarrow Q)$

So you get:

$\forall x ((Cx \land Nx) \rightarrow (\forall y ((Cy \land Ny) \rightarrow Gy) \rightarrow Rx)) \Leftrightarrow $

$\forall x ((Cx \land Nx) \rightarrow \exists y(((Cy \land Ny) \rightarrow Gy) \rightarrow Rx)) \Leftrightarrow $

$\forall x \exists y ((Cx \land Nx) \rightarrow (((Cy \land Ny) \rightarrow Gy) \rightarrow Rx))$

... and you can certainly not switch the order of quantifiers of different types.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Sorry for being a bad student! I will study your advice and I promise to start to learn Latex since the next week.

Comment: May you explain me why in your answer when the universal quantifier (for all y) was moved outside of the parenthesis, the universal quantifier changed to an existential quantifier (there exists a y)? Thank you so much!

Comment: @Beginner OK, I'll add that to the Answer

Comment: Fantastic explanation! You are a great professor! Thanks!